# Recommended format to XML document generic property in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

What is the correct format to XML document the ShoeRun field property of MyClass in C#/VisualStudio

```
MyClass
{
private IMyRunHelp<MyShoeClass> ShoeRun;
}
```

Comment: Those who downvoted probably did so because a) your question is opinion based and we don't like that on Stackoverflow b) the context is unclear (what is IMyRunHelp and MyShoeClass?) which is needed to determine the complexity of the field so that we can find out what level of documentation it deserves.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably very opinion-based. It depends on

- the coding guidelines of your company
- the coding guidelines of your project (which sometimes overrides the company setting)
- the complexity of the field.

  - If it is very simple, maybe it does not need documentation at all.
  - If it's "normal", `//` maybe enough
  - If it's complex, probably `/// <summary>` style would be better.
  - If you're in doubt, discuss it in your team.